# Chrome slow when loading local virtual host

Tags: google-chrome, hosts, mamp

I'm developing a local website with MAMP. I've configured a virtual host (hosts files, and apache vhosts).

`/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   domain.com
```

MAMP Vhosts config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/route/to/folder"
    ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It all works fine, but in Chrome sometimes the local website takes a few seconds to load, when it should load instantly. I've narrowed down the problem to Chrome as it works fine 100% of the time with Safari.

When this happens in Chrome, the status bar at the bottom says "resolving host". It would seem like it's waiting for a DNS server to respond... but isn't the `hosts` file overriding any DNS calls?

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried with a blank Chrome profile, in case it's a setting/extension?

Comment: I've disabled all extensions and the problem persists... As for the settings, I don't see what could be causing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was to move the domain in the `/etc/hosts` file to the same entry as localhost.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost domain.com
```

See [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon).

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer. :)